# SQL Azure vs. On-Premises Timeout Issue - EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm working on a report right now that runs great with our on-premises DB (just refreshed from PROD).  However, when I deploy the site to Azure, I get a SQL Timeout during its execution.  If I point my development instance at the SQL Azure instance, I get a timeout as well.

Goal: To output a list of customers that have had an activity created during the search range, and when that customer is found, get some other information about that customer regarding policies, etc.  I've removed some of the properties below for brevity (as best I can)...

#### UPDATE

After lots of trial and error, I can get the entire query to run fairly consistently within 1000MS so long as this block of code is not executed.

```
CurrentStatus = a.Activities
                                .Where(b => b.ActivityType.IsReportable)
                                .OrderByDescending(b => b.DueDateTime)
                                .Select(b => b.Status.Name)
                                .FirstOrDefault(),
```

With this code in place, things begin to go haywire.  I think this Where clause is a big part of it: `.Where(b => b.ActivityType.IsReportable)`.  What is the best way to grab the status name?

#### EXISTING CODE

Any thoughts as to why SQL Azure would timeout whereas on-premises would turn this around in less than 100MS?

```
return db.Customers
    .Where(a => a.Activities.Where(
        b => b.CreatedDateTime >= search.BeginDateCreated
        && b.CreatedDateTime <= search.EndDateCreated).Count() > 0)
    .Where(a => a.CustomerGroup.Any(d => d.GroupId== search.GroupId))
    .Select(a => new CustomCustomerReport
    {
        CustomerId = a.Id,
        Manager = a.Manager.Name,
        Customer = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
        ContactSource= a.ContactSource!= null ? a.ContactSource.Name : "Unknown",
        ContactDate = a.DateCreated,

        NewSale = a.Sales
            .Where(p => p.Employee.IsActive)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateCreated)
            .Select(p => new PolicyViewModel
            {
                //MISC PROPERTIES
            }).FirstOrDefault(),

        ExistingSale = a.Sales
            .Where(p => p.CancellationDate == null || p.CancellationDate <= myDate)
            .Where(p => p.SaleDate < myDate)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateCreated)
            .Select(p => new SalesViewModel
            {
                //MISC PROPERTIES
            }).FirstOrDefault(),

        CurrentStatus = a.Activities
                            .Where(b => b.ActivityType.IsReportable)
                            .OrderByDescending(b => b.DueDateTime)
                            .Select(b => b.Disposition.Name)
                            .FirstOrDefault(),

        CustomerGroup = a.CustomerGroup
                            .Where(cd => cd.GroupId == search.GroupId)
                            .Select(cd => new GroupViewModel
                            {
                                //MISC PROPERTIES
                            }).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried eager loading explicit on the Activitytype? I mean you woud have an N+1 locally too but perhaps that triggers a different execution plan?

Comment: Have you tried querying this without change tracking in case EF's materialization is taking too long to enumerate the result set and hits the timeout?

Comment: @Pleun - Even with this included, same results... `.Include("Activities.ActivityType")`

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - Indeed.  Did see an improvement.  But not enough to resolve the major challenge with the Activity Type query.

Comment: Have you tried a.Activities.Include(p=>p.ActivityType).Where(p=>p.ActivityType.IsReportable == true).ToList(); then the rest of your query?

Comment: What are the differences between the hardware and dataset on local vs. Azure? How large are your databases on each? Have you tried running subsets of this query on Azure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot give you a definite answer but I would recommend approaching the problem by:

1. Run SQL profiler locally when this code is executed and see what SQL is generated and run. Look at the query execution plan for each query and look for table scans and other slow operations. Add indexes as needed.
2. Check your lambdas for things that cannot be easily translated into SQL. You might be pulling the contents of a table into memory and running lambdas on the results, which will be very slow. Change your lambdas or consider writing raw SQL.
3. Is the Azure database the same as your local database? If not, pull the data locally so your local system is indicative.
4. Remove sections (i.e. CustomerGroup then CurrentDisposition then ExistingSale then NewSale) and see if there is a significant performance improvement after removing the last section. Focus on the last removed section.

Looking at the line itself:

1. You use ".Count() > 0" on line 4. Use ".Any()" instead, since the former goes through every row in the database to get you an accurate count when you just want to know if at least one row satisfies the requirements.
2. Ensure fields referenced in `where` clauses have indexes, such as `IsReportable`.

Comment: Any idea why this line of code is potentially bad?  `.Where(b => b.ActivityType.IsReport)`

Comment: I've tried pulling out piece by piece by piece to find what seems to slow it down, that line appears to be a problem.

Comment: @RSolberg It is hard to say without the underlying database. I am adding one point to my answer but would recommend looking at the generated SQL and working up from there.

Comment: Step 1 here is particularly important. I'm certain that your query plan is going to be very bad and full of table scans and redundant joins. You likely need to optimize some indexes and maybe rework the table schema. This is the leaky abstraction of EF "doing the work" for you... But you'll be able to improve the query once you see the bad plan. :)

Comment: @Haney- I've done this...  EF is definitely doing quite a bit of work here...  What do you think would improve the EF code, without seeing the DB results?

Comment: @RSolberg I suspect that Where clause is slow because the IsReport field is not Indexed, meaning SQL uses a table scan rather than an index seek. However, I cannot be certain without seeing the database schema.

Comment: @Akton - Indeed.  Please post this as an answer.  I was able to get that resolved by profiling the query locally and then using the DB Tuning Advisor.

Comment: @RSolberg I have updated my answer to include adding indexes to fields referenced in where clauses.

Comment: @akton Indexing a bit field won't do much to improve the execution time for the query. Assuming a 50/50 distribution, the query time will be halved and if you assume the query takes 1 second more than the EF timeout time of 30 seconds, the query will still take ~15 seconds which, IMO is still far too much. Any variation on those assumptions will most likely result in a longer query execution time.

Comment: @RaduPorumb True. However, the advice on indexing fields in `where` clauses was intended to be general. There are other cases in the query that could benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use memory.

Long answer:

Because of either bad maintenance plans or limited hardware, running this query in one big lump is what's causing it to fail on Azure. Even if that weren't the case, because of all the navigation properties you're using, this query would generate a staggering number of joins. The answer here is to break it down in smaller pieces that Azure **can** run. I'm going to try to rewrite your query into multiple smaller, easier to digest queries that use the memory of your .NET application. Please bear with me as I make (more or less) educated guesses about your business logic/db schema and rewrite the query accordingly. Sorry for using the query form of LINQ but I find things such as `join` and `group by` are more readable in that form.

```
var activityFilterCustomerIds = db.Activities
    .Where(a => 
        a.CreatedDateTime >= search.BeginDateCreated &&
        a.CreatedDateTime <= search.EndDateCreated)
    .Select(a => a.CustomerId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var groupFilterCustomerIds = db.CustomerGroup
    .Where(g => g.GroupId = search.GroupId)
    .Select(g => g.CustomerId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var customers = db.Customers
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => 
        activityFilterCustomerIds.Contains(c.Id) &&
        groupFilterCustomerIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .ToList();

var customerIds = customers.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var newSales =
    (from s in db.Sales
    where customerIds.Contains(s.CustomerId)
    && s.Employee.IsActive
    group s by s.CustomerId into grouped
    select new
    {
        CustomerId = grouped.Key,
        Sale = grouped
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
            .Select(new PolicyViewModel
            {
                // properties
            })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();


var existingSales = 
    (from s in db.Sales
    where customerIds.Contains(s.CustomerId)
    && (s.CancellationDate == null || s.CancellationDate <= myDate)
    && s.SaleDate < myDate
    group s by s.CustomerId into grouped
    select new
    {
        CustomerId = grouped.Key,
        Sale = grouped
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
            .Select(new SalesViewModel
            {
                // properties
            })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();

var currentStatuses = 
    (from a in db.Activities.AsNoTracking()
    where customerIds.Contains(a.CustomerId)
    && a.ActivityType.IsReportable
    group a by a.CustomerId into grouped
    select new
    {
        CustomerId = grouped.Key,
        Status = grouped
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DueDateTime)
            .Select(x => x.Disposition.Name)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();

var customerGroups =
    (from cg in db.CustomerGroups
    where cg.GroupId == search.GroupId
    group cg by cg.CustomerId into grouped
    select new
    {
        CustomerId = grouped.Key,
        Group = grouped
            .Select(x =>
                new GroupViewModel
                {
                    // ...
                })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();

    return customers
        .Select(c =>
            new CustomCustomerReport
            {
                // ... simple props
                // ...
                // ...
                NewSale = newSales
                    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == c.Id)
                    .Select(x => x.Sale)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
                ExistingSale = existingSales
                    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == c.Id)
                    .Select(x => x.Sale)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
                CurrentStatus = currentStatuses
                    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == c.Id)
                    .Select(x => x.Status)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
                CustomerGroup = customerGroups
                    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == c.Id)
                    .Select(x => x.Group)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
            })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to suggest anything without seeing actual table definitions, espectially the indexes and foreign keys on Activities entity.

As far I understand Activity (CustomerId, ActivityTypeId, DueDateTime, DispositionId). If this is standard warehousing table (DateTime, ClientId, Activity), I'd suggest the following:

1. If number of Activities is reasonably small, then force the use of CONTAINS by

   var activities = db.Activities.Where( x => x.IsReportable ).ToList();

   ...

   .Where( b => activities.Contains(b.Activity) )

You can even help the optimiser by specifying that you want ActivityId.

2. Indexes on Activitiy entity should be up to date. For this particular query I suggest  (CustomerId, ActivityId, DueDateTime DESC)
3. precache Disposition table, my crystal ball tells me that it's dictionary table.
4. For similar task to avoid constantly hitting Activity table I made another small table (CustomerId, LastActivity, LastVAlue) and updated it as the status changed.